# SSL_connect fails with SSL_ERROR_SSL - How can I investigate what is going wrong?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

Simple socket program which is trying to connect to a valid https server (can browse with FireFox/Chrome etc etc).
Code is:

```cpp
// Register the error strings for libcrypto & libssl
SSL_load_error_strings();
// Register the available ciphers and digests
SSL_library_init();
// load all algos
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
// create context (new context for each connection)
ssl_ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
if(!ssl_ctx_) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't initialize ssl context");
}
// create handle
ssl_h_ = SSL_new(ssl_ctx_);
if(!ssl_h_) {
    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx_);
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't initialize new ssl handle");
}
// sd_ is a valid socket connected to a host on port 443,
// i.e. www.repubblica.it:443
// bind socket
if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl_h_, sd_)) {
    SSL_free(ssl_h_);
    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx_);
    throw std::runtime_error("Can't set sd to ssl handle");
}
// set blocking
// this api makes the socket blocking
fd_block(sd_);
// perform handshake
const int r = SSL_connect(ssl_h_);
// r is now -1
if(1 != r) {
    // find out the error
    const int   err = SSL_get_error(ssl_h_, r);
    SSL_free(ssl_h_);
    SSL_CTX_free(ssl_ctx_);
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Can't perform ssl handshake, err code: ") + ssl_err_human(err));
}
```

And I get the following error: `Exception: Can't perform ssl handshake, err code: SSL_ERROR_SSL` which is not really insightful.

What can I do next to understand what I'm doing wrong and then fix it?

Thanks!

Ps. running on Ubuntu 22.04 with default `libssl-dev` package

Comment: If you read the docs `The OpenSSL error queue contains more information on the error.`

Comment: Thanks, error seems to be `error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number`

Comment: So what TLS version are you using and what does the site support?

Comment: Tbh I changed test site... but can try again and see!

Comment: I can see the website is properly accessible via Firefox with TLS 1.3, but ehen if I set in the code: `SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ssl_ctx_, TLS1_3_VERSION)` and `SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version(ssl_ctx_, TLS1_3_VERSION)` it still doesn't work...

Comment: Unfortunately the code is not complete enough to be reproducible. While the error of wrong version number suggests that it is the wrong TLS version, the error is commonly seen when connecting to server which does not speak TLS at all. This for example happens when access needs a proxy but the code is not dealing with the proxy properly. I recommend to do packet captures (wireshark) and compare what your code produces to what a Firefox working on the same system produces.